# Android: Sacar datos de un ArrayLIst de Objetos

Tags: java, android, array

Tengo un problema al sacar datos de un ArrayList de Objectos. Este es mi objeto

```
public class ImageData {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private Bitmap bitmap;
    private String path;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Bitmap getBitmap() {
        return bitmap;
    }

    public void setBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
        this.bitmap = bitmap;
    }

    public String getPath() {
        return path;
    }

    public void setPath(String path) {
        this.path = path;
    }
}
```

Despues en otro Objeto tengo un ArrayList de este objeto

```
public class CheckIn {
    private int folio;
    private String customer;
    private String delivered;
    private ArrayList<ImageData> images;
//    private ArrayList<String> imagePath;

    private static CheckIn instanceCheckIn;

    private CheckIn(){
    }//constructor

    public static CheckIn getInstance() {

        if (instanceCheckIn == null)
            instanceCheckIn = new CheckIn();

        return instanceCheckIn;
    }

    public int getFolio() {
        return folio;
    }

    public void setFolio(int folio) {
        this.folio = folio;
    }

    public String getCustomer() {
        return customer;
    }

    public void setCustomer(String customer) {
        this.customer = customer;
    }

    public String getDelivered() {
        return delivered;
    }

    public void setDelivered(String delivered) {
        this.delivered = delivered;
    }

    public ArrayList<ImageData> getImages() {
        return images;
    }

    public void setImages(ArrayList<ImageData> imageDatasArray) {
        this.images = imageDatasArray;
    }
}
```

Pero lo que quiero hacer es sacar unicamente los Bitmaps del ArrayList porque despues los voy a poner a un ImageView

Comment: Y cúal es la pregunta? Ya tienes los getters de los bitmaps.

Comment: @Chisko la pregunta es cómo obtener el elemento `Bitmap` de las instancias de `ImageData`.

Comment: ah, la duda es sobre la instanciación de clase. Ya veo.

Comment: No comentes "gracias". La forma de agradecer en el sitio es aceptando una respuesta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En tu clase ImageData tienes ya hechos los `get` y `set` de cada una de sus propiedades. Por lo tanto, para obtener sus valores bastaria simplemente con recorrer esta lista, y llamar a su método get para manipularlo y para ir dandoselos a tus `ImageView` :

```
CheckIn checkin = new CheckIn();
for (ImageData object: checkin.getImages()) {
    //Aqui manipulas el valor y los vas seteando a tus imagenes
    object.getBitmap();
}
```

Comment: Hola sioesi, tengo una duda, que significan los dos puntos (:) en el for?

Comment: @Javierfr eso es [enhanced for](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html). En esa página, busca la clase `EnhancedForDemo`

Comment: @Javierfr este tambien se conoce como FOR EACH, se define un tipo de dato (en este caso ImageData) se le asigna un nombre a esta variable (en este caso object) y se le dice de donde proviene ese objeto, que DEBE ser una lista (en este caso un ArrayList de ImageData) por lo tanto object sera una instancia de ImageData dentro de una lista

Answer (score 3):

Otra forma de hacerlo si usas java 8 es con [expresiones lambda](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html)

```
checking.getImages().forEach( o -> {
   // acá manipulas el objeto "o" 
});
```

Si lo que quiere es sacar los `BitMap` sería algo por el estilo:

```
List<BitMap> bitMaps = new ArrayList<>();

checking.getImages().forEach( o -> bitMaps.add(o.getBitMap());
```

Comment: Cool, Creo que ya deberíamos usar esto "expresiones lambda"

Comment: Si :) aparte que tiene muchas funcionalidades, mejora mucho el rendimiento ya que se pueden usar `streams` paralelos.

Comment: !! no habia visto esto :0!! +1 amigo vere que tal eso

Comment: Cuidado. Está la etiqueta Android. Allí no se pueden usar lambdas.

Comment: Creo que ya se puede: https://developer.android.com/guide/platform/j8-jack.html

Comment: Además este es un **mal uso** de lambdas. Los lambdas deben usarse sobre elementos inmutables. Este uso puede romperse en caso que el stream devuelto no sea secuencial.

Comment: Eso depende de si se utilicen paralelStreams, pero para lo que requiere ésta pregunta no me parece que lo sea.

Comment: No se sabe, no es bueno asumir. Simplemente es mal uso de lambdas porque no debes usar elementos inmutables. Además, ya me ha sucedido esto en el pasado y pasé mal rato. La solución por lo menos sería `checking.getImages().stream().map(ImageData::getBitmap).collect(Collectors.toList)`

Answer (score 2):

Pues tendrías que coger la lista de `ImageData` de tu objeto `CheckIn` y recorrerla obteniendo todos los bitmaps y guardándolos en un listado. Sería algo como el código que te pongo a continuación:

```
CheckIn c;
ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmaps = new ArrayList();

for( ImageData img : c.getImages()){
     bitmaps.add(img.getBitmap());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

En ambos objetos tienes métodos tanto guardar las imagene/imagenes como para obtener la imagen/imagenes, el objeto ImageData puede almacenar una imagen, mientras que CheckIn, almacena una lista de imagenes.

Objeto `ImageData` :

```
//Obtiene imagen
public Bitmap getBitmap() {
    return bitmap;
}
//Guarda imagen
public void setBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
    this.bitmap = bitmap;
}
```

Objeto `CheckIn`:

```
//Obtiene lista de imagenes.
public ArrayList<ImageData> getImages() {
    return images;
}

//Guarda lista imagenes.
public void setImages(ArrayList<ImageData> imageDatasArray) {
    this.images = imageDatasArray;
}
```

Por lo tanto para obtener una imagen de la lista de imágenes y esta agregarla a un ImageView, realizas lo siguiente:

```
//Instancias la clase CheckIn
CheckIn checkin = new CheckIn();
//Obtienes un arrayList que obtiene el listado de imagenes.
ArrayList<ImageData> listaImagenes =  checkin.getImages();

Bitmap bitmap;
for (ImageData image: listaImagenes )) {
    //Obtiene imagenes
    bitmap = image.getBitmap();
}
```

También podrías obtener el bitmap en el ArrayList dependiendo del indice en la lista, por ejemplo el segundo elemento (indice 1):

```
Bitmap bitmap = listaImagenes.get(1);
```

al obtener el Bitmap puedes usar el método [setImageBitmap](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap)) para agregar la imagen a tu ImageView:

```
myImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Comment: Elenasys una consulta, porque crear otro ArrayList cuando el get de la clase ya retorna uno?

Comment: En que parte se esta creando otro ArrayList? este se obtiene de checkin.getImages();

Comment: ArrayList<ImageData> listaImagenes =  checkin.getImages(); ?

Comment: Gracias Elenasys

Comment: ahh pues es crear una variable que contenga las imagenes (listaImagenes ) , si quieres leer directamente los elementos simplemente se obtienen en un for (ImageData image: checkin.getImages()) { pero es lo mismo for (ImageData image: listaImagenes ) { es lo mismo pero considerando la pregunta del OP pienso personalmente que puede entender mejor de esta forma

Comment: Haaa ok! Yo solo lo consultaba para ver si era una mejor opcion pero veo que el funcionamiento es el mismo! Gracias @Elenasys :) y quiero tener ese sombrero :(!!

Comment: Es definitivamente lo mismo, yo personalmente haría for (ImageData image: checkin.getImages()) { pero creo que en este caso considero es mejor para el usuario que lo vea de esta forma. Cual sombrero @sioesi ?

Comment: El del grinch xD creo que es ese! @Elenasys